# Laravel Custom Eloquent Method

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have been building queries and repeating code, is there a way to build this into the eloquent model?

I have a model `Transaction` where I am selecting specific currencies. How can I add this into the model? Is there a way of changing this:

```
Transaction::select('*')->where('currency', '=', 'GBP')
```

So that I can do this:

```
Transaction::select('*')->currency('GBP')
```

Then in the model it adds onto the query somehow. I've tried to create `Transaction::currency` but it didn't work. This is just an example and I plan on adding a few selectors to keep the code clean.

```
class Transaction extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'transactions';


    public function currency($query, $currency) {
      return $query->where('currency', '=', $currency);
    }
}
```

Comment: Create Transaction service and write your query there to get data from table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel has such thing called **Query Scopes**. It allows you to do exactly what you want. You just need to prefix your `currency()` method with scope keyword like this:

```
class Transaction extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'transactions';


    public function scopeCurrency($query, $currency) {
      return $query->where('currency', '=', $currency);
    }
}
```

Then you can do this `Transaction::select('*')->currency('GBP')`

Read more about scopes [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#local-scopes)

Comment: Perfect; I knew I was on the right track there. Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

you are almost done,you have to write currency method as query scope.

```
public function scopeCurrency($query, $currency) {
  return $query->where('currency', '=', $currency);
}
```

after doing that you can use scope like this

```
Transaction::select('*')->currency('GBP')
```

For more details go here https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#local-scopes

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using scope.

Add these code to Transaction.php file

```
public function scopeCustom($query, $column, $exp, $value)
{
    return $query->where('votes', $exp, $value);  // ('currency', '=', 'GBP')
}
```

Now use this scope as like

```
Transaction::select('*')->custom('currency', '=', 'GBP');
Transaction::select('*')->custom('amount', '>', 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

After 7 years of your question
there's now a new syntax by Laravel

```
Model::whereColumn('value')->get();
```

> Transaction::whereCurrency('GBP')->get();